# PHP MySQL query: match two tables with percentage match

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables with 'skills', the first one contains the skills of an employee, the second table contains the 'skills' of a company.

**Table employee skills**

```
CREATE TABLE `employee_skills` (
  `e_id` int(8) NOT NULL,
  `skill` int(8) NOT NULL,
  `points` enum('0','25','50','75','100') COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`u_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

**Table company skills**

```
CREATE TABLE `company_skills` (
  `c_id` int(8) NOT NULL,
  `skill` int(8) NOT NULL,
  `points` enum('0','25','50','75','100') COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`u_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

So if a company has 100 points for the skill Windows and a employee 25 points, the match percentage is 25%. I'm using the following query to get the results:

```
$result = $connection->prepare("select u_id, skill, points, COUNT(points) from employee_skills");
```

The expected result should match the certain skills and return a percentage similar to:

skill | match

- windows | 25%
- linux | ...%
- mac | ...%

Comment: you probably looking for `sum(points)` not `count`

Comment: if the employee skill is larger than the company skill, do u want 100% or something like 125%, 150%

Comment: I want percentages below 100%

Comment: Store points as INT. And if Minesh's answer is not what you want consider providing an sqlfiddle along the same lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below:

```
SELECT e_id, e.skill, c.skill, (e.points/c.points)*100 from employee_skills as e, company_skills as c
WHERE e.skill = c.skill
GROUP BY e.e_id,e.skill
```

See below:

```
SELECT c.skill, total_emp_points, c.points as total, 
(total_emp_points/c.points)*100 as percnt FROM company_skills AS c,
(SELECT e.skill, SUM(e.points) as total_emp_points 
    FROM employee_skills as e 
    GROUP BY e.skill) as emp
WHERE c.skill = emp.skill;
```

see **[SqlFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a5008d/6)**

Comment: @JasonB please note that if you want to utilize SUM() function, you need to change data-type of points to remove enum and use int.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I tried some things with SqlFiddle, but if a company scores 100 points on a skill and a employee scores 75 points the query returns 125, instead of a 75(%) match.

Comment: @JasonB Are you looking for employee wise % or total employees' % against company points ?

Comment: In this case I'm looking for total employees' % against company points

Comment: @JasonB Total employees or Average employees ? because if employee A has got 75/100 and employee B has got 50/100, total will be 125/100 , or do you need average (75+50/2)/100 = 62.5 ?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I need (individual) employee A vs.  Company A  and employee X vs. Company Y etc.

Comment: @JasonB in that case, try the 1st SQL in this answer, it will give employee_id, skill, and percentage of individual emp_points